# App aborts when data type of entity changed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have created an entity in my core data and mistakenly kept the type as `String` instead of `Boolean`. When I attempt to change the type to `Boolean`, the app aborts with no exception during the save.

I tried cleaning the app, deleting the folders of simulators, and none worked.

Why is my app aborting after the change?

Comment: delete the app from simulator or device then run.

Comment: Once you change the schema of your table you need to delete the previous install for changes to reflect  as @CoolMonster said

Comment: @CoolMonster please look into my below comment. Do you mean the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your model is not in sync with your persistent store (SQLite db managed by CoreData).

If you have not released your app, you can just delete the app on the simulator (hold the icon down till the cross shows up and then click the cross) and then re-run it. That should delete the persistent store, and create a new one that is in sync with your model.

If your app is already being used by a lot of users, it is not feasible to ask them to delete and reinstall your app every time you change something in your data model. This is where you need something called as Migrations.

Here are Apple’s docs for it — https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html

Here’s a tutorial — http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: my app is still under development. Deleting the app from simulator means library->application support ->iPhone Simulator -> 7.0 (as I am only using this )->application . Delete all the folder. am i right guys  @coolmonster. I have tried this already.

Comment: Run the simulator. Delete the app from the simulator as if you remove the app from your iPhone.

Comment: @Lalit_vicky u delete the app inside the simulator itself just by longpress the app icon and delete the app.